# how do I target <ul> container in FTL

Tags: javascript, css, freemarker

How do I target a `<ul>` container written in freemarker from the js code? I want to display the `<ul>` in ftl on my page by targeting it in the js code. How do I do it?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You target it like you target any other HTML. The thing to realize is that first the FreeMarker template runs on the server and generates the HTML, and then JavaScript run on the client and so only sees the HTML that FreeMarker has generated. It's just plain HTML for the JavaScript.